# top-menu-navigation in css isn't working here, what's wrong with it?

Tags: html, css

top-menu-navigation in css isn't working here, what's wrong with it?
my code is:

```
 /*VARIABLES*/
@link-color: "#000000";
@text-color: "#5b5b5b";
@light-text-color:"c9c9c9";
@heading-font: "Bree Serif";
@body-font: "Arial";

body{
background: transparent url('images/bg.jpg')0 0 repeat;

}

ul{
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.main-header{

background: white;
border-bottom: 1 px solid @boarder color;
}


.top-menu-container{
 background: black;


.top-menu-navigation ul
{
>li {
float: left;
a{
color: green;
}
}
}
}
```

HTML code is"

```
<header class = "main-header" id="top">
<div class = "top-menu-container">
<div class = "container">
<nav class = "top-menu-navigation clearfix">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Top link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Top link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>  <!--end navigation-->
</div>  <!--end container-->
</div>  <!--end top-menu-container-->
</header>
```

Hi I am new in this field and in learning phase. I can't figure out where is the error in the sub class of top-menu-mavigation. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a css preprocessor?  The css you including in your post is not valid css.

Comment: NO how can I add the css preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your header tag and the css is not well formed.
Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/f5mwa/

HTML

```
    <header class = "main-header" id="top">
        <div class = "top-menu-container">
            <div class = "container">
                <nav class = "top-menu-navigation clearfix">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Top link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Top link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>  <!--end navigation-->
            </div>  <!--end container-->
        </div>  <!--end top-menu-container-->
    </header>

CSS

    /*VARIABLES*/
    @link-color: "#000000";
    @text-color: "#5b5b5b";
    @light-text-color:"c9c9c9";
    @heading-font: "Bree Serif";
    @body-font: "Arial";

    body
    {
        background: transparent url('images/bg.jpg')0 0 repeat;
    }

    ul
    {
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }

    .main-header
    {
        background: white;
        border-bottom: 1 px solid @boarder color;
    }


    .top-menu-container
    {
        background: black;
    }
    .top-menu-navigation ul>li
    {
        float: left;
    }
    a
    {
        color: green;
    }
```